# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 after changing project to 64bit supported

Tags: ios, 64-bit

I have recently changed my iOS project to 64bit supported.

The Architectures part now looks like this:

[image]

The Deployment Target is now set to iOS 5.1.1.

I use MDWamp.framework(https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp) for WebSocket connection. It works just fine before I did the change.

Now, Xcode keeps complaining about an error like this:
[image]

The MDWamp version my project used is:

```
//  MDWamp.h
//  MDWamp
//
//  Created by mogui on 08/09/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 mogui. All rights reserved.
```

I have tried re-add the framework but it does not work. I do employ some other 3rd-party frameworks like Three20, and I have successfully solved the same kind of issue by changing their Architectures to `Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - ${ARCHS_STANDARD}`.

I would like to know if this version of MDWamp.framework works for 64bit? If it is, then what should I do to get rid of this error (cause I can't find a proper place to change its Architecture).

Comment: First of all make sure that your target includes the above Framework and I hope you are not using pod.file

Comment: I am sure that I have included the framework, since it works pretty fine until I changed the project to 64bit supported. And, yes, I am not using pod.

Comment: Now make sure that ".m" files from the framework are added to below target
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources

Comment: I am not so sure this time. I only have header files under my MDWamp.framework, `MDWamp.h`, `MDWampMessage.h`, `MDWampProtocols.h`. Where should I get those .m files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the architecture arm64 in your project and if it's not there in the MDWamp third party SDK, then it will show the above error. In order to resolve this you should use the latest version of  MDWamp library which is also built for arm64(if it's available). Also creating the MDWamp third party library for arm64 will only be done by the developer of the static library.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try a new version of MDWamp.framework see if it works.